# How can I consume all messages from an AuditQueue in Rebus using SQLServerPersistance?

Tags: auditing, rebus

I have Rebus'es Message Auditing feature turned on but currently nothing to consume the messages ending up in the queue.  I want to be able to consume all the messages and simply write them to offline storage.

I don't need my AuditConsumer service to know about all the different types of messages, I just want to get the json data and write it to a file.

Is it possible to do this in Rebus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way (out of the box) to do what you are requesting - this is something that you would need to do yourself.

You could fairly easily script something, though, that would use the `SqlServerTransport` to receive the messages from the audit "queue" and append them to a file.

In the future Rebus will probably come with more options in this area in order to support the upcoming Fleet Manager (which will be a commercial all-in-one message auditing, debugging, and visualization tool).